# windres tool of mingw32 utility is generating file name with ^M character

Tags: unix, windres

I am trying to generate one resource file using `windres` tool of `mingw32` utils in Linux using the below command:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-windres my.rc -O coff my.res
```

But, it is generating a file with name `my.res^M`. I verified this with `ls -l` command. Please explain why `^M` is added in the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was file conversion. I need to convert my .sh file in unix format if downloaded or retrieved from windows platform.

dos2unix .sh file helps